# unique form validation based on two fields

Tags: laravel, validation, unique

I am creating a new record for a table named `services` including some fields (`name`, `department_id`, `description`) in database. I need unique combination of pair two fields together (`name` and `department_id`). How can I validate it for creating and updating functions?

In ServiceRequest:

```
return [
          'params.name' => 'required|unique:services,name and depatment_id',
       ];
```

In Service Model:

```
public function department()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
}
```

In DepartmentModel:

```
public function services()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Service::class);
}
```

In Route:

```
Route::apiResource('/services', ServiceController::class)->names([
    'store' => 'services_store',
    'update' => 'services_update',
]);
```

Forexample:

when there is a service in a specific department, it gives error!
if there is a record of `name = service1` and `department_id = 1`, user cannot create same record combination of `name` and `department_id` again! user allow to create service with (`name = service1` and `department_id = another_number`) or (`department_id = 1` and `name = another_name`) but creating a new record with (`name = service1` and `department_id = 1`) is not allowed

Comment: You can add a second unique rule

Comment: I need them together be unique.. not each filed alone be an unique one

Comment: I misunderstood, I thought you wanted `params.name` itself to be unique across two database fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `unique` rule this way:

```php
return [
    'params.name' => [
        'required', 
        Rule::unique('services', 'name')
            ->ignore($this->service)
            ->where('department_id', $this->input('params.department_id'))
     ],
];
```

Here you are telling Laravel to check if there is no existing record in the `services` table that have `$this->input('params.name')` as `name` and `$this->input('params.department_id')` as `department_id`.

The `->ignore($this->service)` is here to make sure we ignore the current service (if we are updating), so it doesn't "find itself" during the validation.

*`$this->service` will be the current instance you are updating (if you setup the routes and controllers correctly, which is another topic).*

Comment: Thank you.. but It gives me this error! `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'field1' in 'where clause'` (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `services` where `field1` = test and (`field1` is null and `field2` is null))

Comment: These columns are just placeholders, you have to replace them with your actual columns

Comment: I know.. this is my real validation: `return [ 'params.name' => ['required', Rule::unique('services')->where(function($q){$q->where('name', $this->input('params.name'))->where('department_id', $this->input('params.department_id')); })],];`

Comment: But it gives me this error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'params.name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `services` where `params`.`name` = test and (`name` = test and `department_id` = 1))"`

Comment: Can you update your question with all the actual data please? I mean by including the form, the database structure, models... and with an example of what you are trying to achieve. I think there is a misunderstanding by either you, me or both.

Comment: I updated it and add some more details.. I hope it'll be cleared..

Comment: If i'm understanding well, you want an unique combination of `name` and `department_id`. Are you updating a Service in this request? If not, do you have a `department_id` in your request body? I mean, what you are trying to achieve is impossible without having both `name` and `department_id` at some point, so I guess the question is missing some key information here. Can you update it with everything? The route you are using, the form you are sending, ideally the output of a `dd($this->all());` (in your `rules` method) would also be great.

Comment: yes, I want an unique combination of `name` and `department_id` and I also need updating it..

Comment: I updated my answer. There should be no `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'params.name' in 'where clause'` since we never try to update such column. Don't replace `where('name', ...` by `where('params.name'...` and it should be fine.

Comment: Your solution seems completely logical. I wrote your answer but unfortunately, I have same error again! I'm using Laravel 8.. I wonder its because of Laravel version or not!

Comment: Can you update your question with the entire error trace please?

Comment: "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'params.name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `services` where `params`.`name` = test22 and (`name` = test22 and `department_id` = 1))",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
    "file": "D:\\projects\\nobatdehi\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php",
    "line": 692,

Comment: I used this `Rule::unique('services', 'name')` to call `name` column instead `params.name` column and it works well.. Thank you a lot!

Comment: I was doing some tests and I was about to update my answer with this solution! You can also make it shorter, see the updated answer. Have a nice day!